# Prolog function returning true instead of value for variable

Tags: prolog

I have a problem in which I have two lists and I need to compare their elements and return a list with the greater element of the two.

For Example:   the query: listsMax([2,5,11,25,9], [2,9,10,20,12], M).
    should result in:  M = [2,9,11,25,12].

My problem is that after running the above query, it is returning me true instead of the value for M.

I'm new to Prolog and I really don't understand why this is happening.

I've already tried changing listMax([],[],M). to listMax([ _ ],[ _ ],M). But I really don't know much else.

Here's my code:

```
    listMax([],[],M).
    listMax([L1|R1],[L2|R2],M) :-
       compare(L1,L2,N),
       listsMax(R1,R2,Z),
       head(Z, N, M).

    compare(L1, L2, N) :- L1 > L2, N is L1.
    compare(L1, L2, N) :- L1 <= L2, N is L2.

    head(T, H, [H|T]).
```

Here, I am using compare() to find out the bigger of the two numbers and using head() to add the provided element to the head of the list also provided.

This is my query:

```
-? listMax([2,5,11,25,9], [2,9,10,20,12], M).
```

Expected:

```
 M = [2,9,11,25,12].
```

Actual:

```
true.
```

Comment: `compare/3` is a build-in predicate! Try `compare(R,a,b)` which should have `R = (<)` as answer.

Comment: can not reproduce. doubleplusungood. very disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix the recursive definition:

```
max_of_two_lists([], [], []).
max_of_two_lists([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [M|Ms]) :-
    max_of_two(X, Y, M),
    max_of_two_lists(Xs, Ys, Ms).
```

You could re-write this using `maplist`:

```
max_of_two_lists(Xs, Ys, Ms) :-
    maplist(max_of_two, Xs, Ys, Ms).
```

If the arguments are numbers (or arithmetic expressions), you can use the `max()` arithmetic function (in SWI-Prolog):

```
max_of_two(X, Y, M) :- M is max(X, Y).
```

If you want to compare using the standard order of terms:

```
max_of_two(X, Y, M) :- X @> Y, !, X = M.
max_of_two(X, Y, M) :- /* X @=< Y, !, */ Y = M.
```